# How to Bind Event to CheckBox in UltimateListCtrl?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I have been trying to figure out how to use wx.UltimateListCtrl in Python to create a customized widget. Based on some internet examples I have this basic script but i'm stuck in how to bind events inside the widget in order to get the stringtext from column 1 if checkBox in column two is selected.
This is the code:

```
import sys
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "UltimateListCtrl Demo")

        list = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, agwStyle=ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT|wx.LC_REPORT|wx.LC_VRULES|wx.LC_HRULES|wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)
        list.InsertColumn(0, "File Name")
        list.InsertColumn(1, "Select")

        for _ in range(4):
            index = list.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, "Item " + str(_))
            list.SetStringItem(index, 1, "")
            checkBox = wx.CheckBox( list, wx.ID_ANY, u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            list.SetItemWindow(index, 1, checkBox , expand=True)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(list, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        checkBox1.Bind( wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, checkBoxOnCheckBox )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def checkBoxOnCheckBox( self, event ):
        print 'Yes'
        #event.Skip()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()  
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance for your help
Ivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: Try not to name the ULC list as this masks the Python list.

There are of course multiple ways to do what you want. One solution is to keep a reference of the checkbox and link it with the index of the item. This way you can identify the item.

I hope this helps.

```
import sys
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.ultimatelistctrl as ULC


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "UltimateListCtrl Demo")

        agwStyle = (ULC.ULC_HAS_VARIABLE_ROW_HEIGHT | wx.LC_REPORT |
                    wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL)

        self.mylist = mylist = ULC.UltimateListCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY,
                                                    agwStyle=agwStyle)
        mylist.InsertColumn(0, "File Name")
        mylist.InsertColumn(1, "Select")

        self.checkboxes = {}

        for _ in range(4):
            index = mylist.InsertStringItem(sys.maxint, "Item " + str(_))
            mylist.SetStringItem(index, 1, "")
            checkBox = wx.CheckBox(mylist, wx.ID_ANY, u"", wx.DefaultPosition,
                                   wx.DefaultSize, 0)
            self.checkboxes[checkBox.GetId()] = index
            mylist.SetItemWindow(index, 1, checkBox, expand=True)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(mylist, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.checkBoxOnCheckBox)

    def __del__(self):
        pass

    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def checkBoxOnCheckBox(self, event):
        cb = event.GetEventObject()
        idx = self.checkboxes[cb.GetId()]
        print(self.mylist.GetItemText(idx))
        print(cb.GetValue())
        event.Skip()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()  
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Your code helped me a lot in understanding how to deal with multiple widgets and respective bindings. Thank you.